# Setting key on data.table produces different order than sort()?

Tags: r, data.table

Typically, setting a key on a `data.table` orders it:

```
> foo <- data.table(x = c(8,6,7,5,3,0,9))
> setkey(foo, x)
> foo
   x
1: 0
2: 3
3: 5
4: 6
5: 7
6: 8
7: 9
```

But not in this case:

```
> foo <- data.table(x = c(1234567890.02, 1234567890.01))
> setkey(foo, x)
> foo - 1234567890
            x
1: 0.01999998
2: 0.00999999
```

In contrast, the base `sort` function orders it correctly:

```
> sort(foo$x) - 1234567890
[1] 0.00999999 0.01999998
```

I guess there's some loss of precision when applying `data.table`'s sorting algorithm...  But why?

Comment: In `v1.9.7` it is working fine.  Can you try loading `library(bit64)`

Comment: See `?setNumericRounding` and set it to 0, or v1.9.7 has changed the default to 0.  (Unrelated to `bit64`).

Comment: Ah, yes I was using v1.9.6.  After calling `setNumericRounding(0)` it now orders them as desired. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Dowle basically answered this in his comment, but to sum up:

In `data.table` `v1.9.6` and earlier, the default behavior when joining/grouping/ordering numeric columns was to round the last two bytes off the significand.  This behavior can be changed by calling `setNumericRounding`.

The justification for this default was not for speed, but rather to avoid surprising results such as:

```
DT = data.table(a=seq(0,1,by=0.2),b=1:2, key="a")
DT
setNumericRounding(0)   # turn off rounding
DT[.(0.4)]   # works
DT[.(0.6)]   # no match, confusing since 0.6 is clearly there in DT
```

(Example taken from the `?setNumericRounding` documentation. [link](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.9.6/topics/setNumericRounding))

However, this default behavior produces unexpected orderings in cases like I gave in this question.  See also [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1642)

To address such issues, the default is changed to `setNumericRounding(0)` in `v1.9.7` (currently in development on [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/) at the time of this posting).